# How to set the default parameters of Conv2D in tf.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Support i have a network with 5 convolution. I write it by Keras.

```py
x = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
y = Conv2D(10, 3, strides=1)(x)
y = Conv2D(16, 3, strides=1)(y)
y = Conv2D(32, 3, strides=1)(y)
y = Conv2D(48, 3, strides=1)(y)
y = Conv2D(64, 3, strides=1)(y)
```

I want set all convolution's `kernel_initializer` to xavier. One of method is:

```py
x = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
y = Conv2D(10, 3, strides=1, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())(x)
y = Conv2D(16, 3, strides=1, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())(y)
y = Conv2D(32, 3, strides=1, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())(y)
y = Conv2D(48, 3, strides=1, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())(y)
y = Conv2D(64, 3, strides=1, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())(y)
```

But this kind of writing is very sad and the code is very redundant.

Is there a better way of writing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keras provides no way to change the defaults, so you can just make a wrapper function:

```
def myConv2D(filters, kernel):
    return Conv2D(filters, kernel, strides=1, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())
```

And then use it as:

```
x = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
y = myConv2D(10, 3)(x)
y = myConv2D(16, 3)(y)
y = myConv2D(32, 3)(y)
y = myConv2D(48, 3)(y)
y = myConv2D(64, 3)(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better make a `lambda` that will make a `Conv2D` layer and fix the initializer as needed and call it in the model definition part.

I think lambda is more suitable in this situation than a function.

You can do it like this,

```
customConv = lambda filters, kernel : Conv2D(filters, kernel, strides=1, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())

x = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))

y = customConv(10, 3)(x)
y = customConv(16, 3)(y)
y = customConv(32, 3)(y)
y = customConv(48, 3)(y)
y = customConv(64, 3)(y)
```